# Apply wordnet on string to words vector filter output

Tags: java, filter, output, wordnet

I've applied a string to word vector filter on 100 message as follows

```
try{  
     stwv.setOutputWordCounts(true); 
     stwv.setTFTransform(true);
     stwv.getAttributeIndices();
     stwv.setStopwords(value);  
     stwv.setAttributeIndices("2");
     stwv.setMinTermFreq(1);
     stwv.setWordsToKeep(10000);
     stwv.setTFTransform(true);
     stwv.setInputFormat(data);
     stwv.setTokenizer(wt);

     Instances output = weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(data, stwv);

     reorder.setAttributeIndices("2-last,1");
     reorder.setInputFormat(output);

     Instances outputorder=weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(output,reorder);
```

Then I applied a reorder filter to make class attribute the last attribute.

I want to apply wordnet on `outputorder`.

How can perform this?

Comment: It is not clear what which libraries you are using and which type the elements in your code snippets are.  You need to provide more  context information. Like what do you mean with "apply wordnet"? Do you want to filter the list or even vector of words using Wordnet?  Which WordNet library are you using? The paper [Java Libraries for Accessing the PrincetonWordnet: Comparison and Evaluation](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/download.php?f=finlayson.2014.procgwc.7.x.pdf) lists 12 Java Libraries. What have you tried and where are you struggling?

Comment: i using weka libraries in java netbeans to classify messages into spam and ham. first perform preprocessing these messages by string to words filter in weka ,now i have seperate words now i want perform wordnet on these words result from string to words vector filter how can perform this ??????

Comment: There are different resources available on the net simply like the [Weka Text Mining Cookbook](http://www.esp.uem.es/jmgomez/tmweka/). There is also the [SentiWordNetDemo on Github](https://github.com/jmgomezh/tmweka/blob/master/OpinionMining/SentiWordNetDemo.java) or the [RiTaWordNetFilter](https://github.com/dhowe/RiTa/blob/master/java/rita/wordnet/WordnetFilters.java)  Which may be something you are looking for.  You need to provide more information like which WordNet Library you are using and what's exactly your problem.  Just asking to do something will not work.

Comment: i want find wordnet synsets in weka

Comment: You want to implement a Stemming Algorithm / a `weka.core.stemmers.Stemmer` for Weka based on WordNet. Is that what you want? Still you did not tell which WordNet Library you want to use. Here for example  is quite similar question on Stackoverflow [Getting word stems with JWI and Wordnet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362168/getting-word-stems-with-jwi-and-wordnet)

Comment: i want apply wordnet in weka to find synsets from dictionary that i added for each word in sms dataset.arff ,are can perform this in weka???? and can i added jwnl or jaw library for wordnet to weka???

Comment: I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be possible to add jwnl or jaw libraries to a java application that uses the java weka library. Just try it out. Have a look at the links I've provided you. And if you have concrete problems you can ask it here.